# Response to 2001 Toyota Carolla vvt code 1349: what should I do?

Tags: electrical, toyota, corolla, electronic-control-module, code

I got a vvt 1349 code on my 2001 Toyota Carolla. I have noticed a sharp decrease in fuel economy. Some people have reported that the oil control valve may be causing the issue. The oil control valve can [be seen in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cV8aWhHpYEk). Other have suggested that the oil control valve's filter ([seen in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnbJ6-nc6Oo)) could be causing the problem.

When my mechanic looked up the code he said this could cost upwards of $2000. I think the best first step here is to examine the oil control valve, the associated filter, and the cam sensor. My mechanic says he needs to plug his computer into my car to do some diagnostics before he moves forward.

Is there anything else I can do to prepare for this visit?

What, besides the oil control valve, associated filter, and cam sensor, could be causing this problem?

Comment: Assuming your engine oil is OK and the car has seen regular oil changes. The oil control valve is always the #1 suspect. I've never had to replace a cam sensor for VVT issues, same with the oil control valve filter. If and this is a big if, oil changes weren't done regularly the camshaft phaser may get stuck in an advanced or retarded position.

Comment: Thanks! I drove with low oil for a while. The oil light didn't turn on but when I checked the dip stick it was at he very bottom dot. How much damage am I doing driving my car until I take it to the mechanic?

Comment: Bottom dot is minimum level you're low roughly 1 qt at the bottom dot. Just make sure it's in the cross hatch and you'll be fine until you can get your car in.

Comment: After driving it for a few days the light turned off. I imagine that the oil control valve was clogged and became unclogged. Is it worthwile to still take it in to the mechanic? My current plan is to wait and see the mechanic only if the light turns back on.

Comment: If your engine was low on oil when the check engine light came on that was more than likely the cause. Just make sure to keep an eye on oil level and if the code comes back than take it to your mechanic for further diagnosis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a [Toyota Technical Service Bulletin (TSB) #EG009-03](http://www.toyotapart.com/M.I.L._ON_DTC_P1349_-_VVTi_ACTUATOR_T-EG009-03.pdf) which talks about this very problem with the VVTi engines.

The bulletin gives the following steps to diagnosing/fixing the issue:

> 1. Inspect the condition of the valve cover oil baffle as per TSB EG007–02. If camshaft or camshaft position sensor damage resulting from a bent baffle is identified, repair the damage as necessary.
> 2. Make sure the vehicle is in “PARK” with the engine idling.
> 3. Referring to the screen flow below, connect the Toyota Diagnostic Tester to the vehicle and select the VVT Control Bank One Active Test (VVT CTRL B1) from the Active Test Menu.

What the service bulletin talks about next (step #4) is using their diagnostic tester. I know the average Joe doesn't have one of these, so we have to do the next step in a different way. Basically what they are asking the technician to do is to turn the VVTI actuator on manually. For us to do this, all we have to do is apply power to the actuator and listen to see if there is a change in how the engine runs. I guess the first thing you have to do is figure out where the VVTi actuator is located at. I believe on your car it is here:

[image]

To test it, unplug the actuator (in the image it's called a Camshaft Timing Oil Control Valve. It's the part which allows the oil pressure to feed to the Controller. After you have it unplugged, have the engine running and up to temp. Then apply power to the actuator. The TSB goes on to say:

> 5. If at this point the vehicle does not run rough and/or stalls when the active test is performed, proceed with Repair Manual P1349 VVTi Fault Isolation Procedure (FIP). If the vehicle does stall and/or runs rough, this indicates the the VVTi control system is operating. Proceed to replace the VVTi actuator following the repair procedures listed on the Technical Information System (TIS): Engine Mechanical Section, Camshaft, Replacement.

When the technician attaches his equipment to your car, he'll be looking to see which way he needs to go with the repairs. I'm pretty sure it will be limited to the three things you mentioned above in your question.

Comment: That's a nice service bulletin find!